# Can you make Google search results category (web, images, maps, etc.) show on top?

Tags: google-search, google-chrome

I was using a public computer the other day and was surprised to find google search results rendered a little differently on its Chrome than on my laptop's Chrome.

Basically, the search results category bar on the left (that says Web, Images, Maps, Videos, etc.) was moved to the top of the page, so there was more space for the results to show up across the row.

Where is this option hidden in Google? Or was this created by an extension in Chrome?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is obsolete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google are updating their site layout to the look you experienced, but it is a progressive rollout. Whether you get it at the moment is probably depending on factors like which server farm you get, but it will be standard soon.

According to [this post](http://insidesearch.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/spiffing-up-your-search-results-page.html) by Google:

> It’s going out to Google.com users in the U.S. to start, and we want to get it to users in other languages and regions as soon as we can.